# Doubt on conditional expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-function, expected-value

Let $S$ and $T$ two random indipendent variables with exponential distribution, and let $\mathbb{E}(S)=\alpha,\mathbb{E}(T)=\beta$ .

- 1) Find the distribution of $Y=\min(S,T)$.

$\rightarrow Y\sim Exp(\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta})$

- 2) Find the probability of event $\mathbb{P}(S<T)$.

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(S<T)=\frac{1}{2}$

Given that these two points I believe they're correct, I have a doubt on the following third point:

- 3) Find $\mathbb{E}(S+T|S>4)$.

$\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(S+T|S>4)=\mathbb{E}(S+T|S>4,T>0)=\mathbb{E}(S|S>4)+\mathbb{E}(T|T>0)=$ 
$\mathbb{E}(S|S>4)+\mathbb{E}(T)=4+\alpha +\beta$.

Is it correct?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\min$ using `\min`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @joriki Thanks, I edited.

Comment: $P(S<T)=0.5$ is true if $\alpha = \beta$, but not in general.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Thanks for your answer. I wrote: $\mathbb{P}(S<T)=\mathbb{P}(T>S)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}[\int_{s}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha \beta}e^{-(\frac{s}{\alpha}+\frac{t}{\beta})}dt]ds$ and I obtain $\frac{1}{2}$. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Francesco Totti (friendly... er pupone?)

The integral is correct but the solution is $\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$

intermediate result

$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-s \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha \beta}}ds$

3) it is correct but simply

$\mathbb{E}[S+T|S>4]=\mathbb{E}[S|S>4]+\mathbb{E}[T|S>4]=4+\mathbb{E}[S]+\mathbb{E}[T]$

a) $\mathbb{E}[S|S>4]=4+\mathbb{E}[S]$ follows immediately from lack of memory property

b) $\mathbb{E}[T|S>4]=\mathbb{E}[T]$ follows immediately from independence between S and T